# delay MockWebServer response

Tags: android, square, okhttp, mockwebserver

How can I delay a Square MockWebServer HTTP response?

There is a `response.setBodyDelayTimeMs(...);` method but this is only used in SpdySocketHandler and not for HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug that we OkHttp maintainers need to fix. If you report it on our issue tracker, we'll tale care of it. Or better yet, send us a pull request!

Answer (score 1):

`response.setBodyDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

This should now work for HTTP requests as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val serverFoo = MockWebServer().apply {
        dispatcher = object : Dispatcher() {
            override fun dispatch(request: RecordedRequest): MockResponse {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)
                return MockResponse()
            }
        }
    }
```