# MockWebServer response delay - testing timeouts

Tags: timeout, retrofit, delay, okhttp, mockwebserver

I'm trying to test HTTP timeout scenarios using a MockWebServer which answers my test requests sent with Retrofit/OkHttp. (This question [was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778379/delay-mockwebserver-response) some years ago, but at the time concerned a bug in the MockWebServer. Also, the API has since changed a fair bit, so I think reposting this question is warranted.)

There seem to be several related methods, but I'd appreciate a solution to this issue with a clear example: I'm unsure about the difference between..

- `.delayBody` and
- `.throttleBody`

Also, both of these methods seem to only delay/throttle the body - is it not possible to set a timeout for the response header? I.e. something along the lines of "wait X seconds after the next incoming request before you send out any response".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delay MockWebServer response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778379/delay-mockwebserver-response)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try setting the response’s socket policy to NO_RESPONSE.

Comment: +1 Worked like a charm, **and** pointed me to the very useful SocketPolicy API which I somehow totally missed so far...

Comment: I want to mock retrofit request so that timeout happens. Can i use this method?

Comment: When setting up the retrofit service, ensure that you've set your read timeout to something small so you don't end up with an unnecessary long running test.

Comment: This doesnt return a SocketTimeoutException. It returns "HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream"

Answer (score 7):

The `setSocketPolicy()` method is deprecated.

```
MockResponse mockResponse = new MockResponse().setBodyDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will delay the MockWebServer response by 10 seconds.

Comment: `setSocketPolicy()` is *un*-deprecated since okhttp 4.3: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/src/main/kotlin/mockwebserver3/MockResponse.kt

Answer (score 1):

I tried many of the suggested ways of doing it but no luck. I think it should be just right to not mock return any response and you request will timeout but you need to make sure that your test case request response does not interfere with other test cases responses by reseting your mocked server for each test.
At the end of the day, a timeout is no response, isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, the following is what fgysin should try:

```
MockResponse mockResponse = new MockResponse().setHeadersDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```